# JavaScript: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string"

Tags: javascript

Does anyone could tell what is wrong in this line?

`var jquery = "jquery="+base+":nth-child("+index")";`

I have tried different combinations with " and ' but none of them worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a '+' sign after index;
try

```
var jquery = "jquery="+base+":nth-child("+index+")";
```

Comment: @pingwin850 Please accept answer if it working for you.